# XMLUnit show added or removed nodes

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

I have two xml files like this:

```
<personlist>
    <person>
        <name>Test</name>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Test2</name>
    </person>
</personlist>
```

and this

```
<personlist>
    <person>
        <name>Test</name>
    </person>
</personlist>
```

I know want to use `XMLUnit` to get the difference between these two xml files.
Is there a way that `XMLUnit` shows me what nodes are added or removed?
If I compare the xml files i want a result like:

```
1 person node removed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added and removed nodes are a special kind of difference. So you need to use one of the methods that give you all differences. If using XMLUnit 1.x that means using `DetailedDiff` and `getAllDifferences` - if using XMLUnit 2.x that means looking at `Diff` and `getDifferences` and most likely `DiffBuilder`.

XMLUnit will flag a difference with either the control or the test node detail being `null` with type `CHILD_NODE_NOT_FOUND_ID` in 1.x and `CHILD_LOOKUP` in 2.x. If the test detail is `null`, the node has been removed. If the control detail is `null` it has been added.

When using XMLUnit 1.x ensure to set `XMLUnit.setCompareUnmatched(false)` or you may not receive any `CHILD_NODE_NOT_FOUND` differences at all.

Answer (score 0):

What about this method?

```
public class DifferenceinXMLTest extends XMLTestCase {
  @Test
  public void test() {
    final String xml1 = ""
    final String xml2 = ""
    XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true); // ignore whitespace differences
    assertXMLEquals(xml1, xml2);  // assertXMLEquals comes from XMLTestCase
  }
}
```

To get the list you can use detaileddiff class.

Some examples - 
http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.custommonkey.xmlunit.DetailedDiff

http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/example.html

Comment: This only test if the two xml files are identically. But i want XMLUnit to show me whats the difference between the two files. Especially i want to know what nodes where added or removed.

Comment: Updates answer - hope that helps.